# Return a List with multiple results using LINQ and EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this simple method that returns a user:

```
User usr = ReliableExecution.RetryWithExpression<User, User>(u => u.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserEmail == userEmail));
```

Now I need to create a similar method, but I need to return a list

```
List<Asset> lst = ReliableExecution.RetryWithExpression<Asset, List<Asset>>(u => u.SelectMany(x => x.EventId == eventId));
```

My problem is with the [SelectMany(x => x.EventId == eventId)] part that doesn't compile and I can't understand exactly how to use LINQ to get multiple results.
I have specified "SelectMany" just for an example, it can be whatever you find correct.

This is the signature of RetryWithExpression for reference:

```
   public static TValue RetryWithExpression<T, TValue>(Func<ObjectSet<T>, TValue> func, Int32 retryInfiniteLoopGuard = 0)
         where T : class
```

Comment: Why are you specifying a condition in `SelectMany`? Shouldn't it be `Where` instead?

Comment: When I use Where this is what I get: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Asset>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Asset>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your expression should be rewritten as follows:

```
List<Asset> lst = ReliableExecution
    .RetryWithExpression<Asset, List<Asset>>(
        u => u.Where(x => x.EventId == eventId).ToList()
    );
```

In simple terms, `SelectMany` flattens a "list of lists of items A" into a "list of items B" using a functor that extracts a list of items B from each single item A; this is not what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want:

```
List<Asset> lst = ReliableExecution.RetryWithExpression<Asset, List<Asset>>
                  (u => u.SelectMany(x => x.Where(y => y.EventId == eventId)));
```

`SelectMany` expects the passed `Func` to return an `IEnumerable`, which it then flattens. You were passing through a list of `Asset` and then trying to select the `EventId` directly on the list. What you really wanted was to select all Assets in the list with matching `EventId`, hence the extra `Where` clause.